# Is it possible to detect wether an AdMob ad was displayed?

Tags: android, admob

For example: let's say an AdMob fails, or more likely, the user is using an AdBlocker to block the ads.

Is there any way to detect this so I can show an in-house ad instead of nothing?  The in-house ad would just tell the user to purchase the premium version to remove ads.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a listener to the AdView:

```
AdView admob = (The inflated view)
admob.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
  @Override
  public void onReceiveRefreshedAd(AdView arg0) {}

  @Override
  public void onReceiveAd(AdView arg0) {}

  @Override
  public void onFailedToReceiveRefreshedAd(AdView arg0) {}

  @Override
  public void onFailedToReceiveAd(AdView arg0) {}
});
```

You can then implement the needed steps in the provided callback functions (onFailedToReceive...)

Comment: On thing to note about this is that receiving the same ad twice in a row seems to not cause any of these to be called when you are automatically refreshing the ad using setRefreshInterval.